# (c++) terminate called after throwing an instance of

Tags: c++

I encounter this error in my program 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'', here's my code:

grade.h

```
    #ifndef GRADE_H_
    #define GRADE_H_

    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Grade
    {
        int mid_term, final;
        double total;

        public:
            Grade *next;
            Grade();
            Grade(int i_mid_term, int i_final);
            void readFile(string _file);
            void printList();
            void subString(string s);
            void Show();
            void addTail(Grade *q);
    };

    #endif
```

grade.cpp

```
#include "grade.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

Grade *tail;
Grade *head;

Grade::Grade(int i_mid_term, int i_final)
{
    mid_term = i_mid_term;
    final = i_final;
//  total = i_total;
}

Grade::Grade()
{
    head = tail = NULL;
}

void Grade::addTail(Grade *q)
{
        if (tail != NULL){
            tail -> next = q;
        }else{
            head = tail = q;
        }
        tail = q;
        q -> next = NULL;
}


void Grade::readFile(string _file)
    {
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open(_file.c_str());
        if(!fin.is_open())
        {
            cout<<"Can't read.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            string s = "";
            while (getline(fin, s))
            {
                subString(s);
            }
            fin.close();
        }   
    }

void Grade::printList()
    {
        Grade *q;
        cout<<"The grade list is:\n";
        q = head;
        int i = 1;
        while (q != NULL)
        {
            cout<<"\nGrade no: "<<i<<endl;
            q-> Show();
            q = q->next;
            i++;
        }
    }

void Grade::subString(string s)
    {
        int mid_term; 
        int final;
        string temp;
        // Mid
        int mark = s.find(":");
        mid_term = atoi(s.substr(0,mark).c_str());
//      cout << mid_term << endl;
        // Final 
        temp = temp.substr(mark+1);
        mark = temp.find(":");
        final = atoi(temp.substr(0, mark).c_str());
//      cout << final << endl;

        Grade *q = new Grade(mid_term, final);

        this -> addTail(q);
    }

void Grade::Show()
    {
        cout << mid_term << "-" << final << endl;
    }
```

The compiler doesn't show any errors or warnings, which makes it difficult to find the bug. This is the first time I had this problem. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: You should find the bug with a debugger instead of relying on a compiler to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@YePhIcK is correct. This is a run-time error, not a compile error. The likely culprit is one of your `substr` calls in `Grade::subString`. My money is on

```
temp = temp.substr(mark+1);
```

It will cause problems if the first colon isn't found.

A cheap way to find the error is to wrap your code in a try/catch (std::exception) and keep narrowing that until you find the offending line. A debugger is probably a better solution, though.

Comment: @Marco Mind marking the question as solved then? And you're welcome.